# program is not going in the first if statement even if all the textview r empty

Tags: android, textview

```
  if(binding.petname.getText().toString().isEmpty() && binding.age.toString().isEmpty() &&
                  binding.petname.toString().isEmpty() && binding.color.toString().isEmpty()
                  && binding.phone.toString().isEmpty() && binding.pettype.toString().isEmpty()){

              Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Enter The Required Field's", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          }else {
              if (binding.vacinated.isChecked())
                  Vacinated=true;
              else if(binding.nonvacinated.isChecked())
                  Vacinated=false;
              else if(!binding.vacinated.isChecked() && !binding.nonvacinated.isChecked()){

                  Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Not Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  return;
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in some of the comparision inside `if` you forgot to call `.getText()`

```
if(binding.petname.getText().toString().isEmpty() && binding.age.getText().toString().isEmpty() &&
              binding.petname.getText().toString().isEmpty() && binding.color.getText().toString().isEmpty()
              && binding.phone.getText().toString().isEmpty() && binding.pettype.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
```